# Wordpress pages stopped working on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, localhost

I was running a wordpress site and I had installed a quick cache plugin and installed it way before. I was working on xamp server localhost and my pages suddenly stopped working. The site is not hosted but it is on my local machine.

I inspected the not opening page and I get below error in console. Can you please help as no page of my site is opening and I am getting below error.

GET http://localhost:8080/sk/ net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Thanks,
Zeeshan Durrani

Answer (score 0):

Can you disabled the plugin and turn the WP error reporting on?

What errors does that provide you with?

Comment: To enable reporting: find wp-config.php file, and set the WP_DEBUG constant to true.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem now. Had to restart my Win 8 to get things working again.